# Another site is showing up underneath my site's search result

Tags: google-app-engine, seo, subdomain

I have a site hosted on Google AppEngine under the appspot.com domain. My site is called antplanner.appspot.com but someone else cloned my site under a different appspot domain, antplanner-fork.appspot.com.

Now when I search for my site on Google, the other site shows up under my search result. (see below image). Is there anything I can do to remove the other site from my result?

[image]

Comment: This belongs on webmasters.se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a service called [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools), which -- among other things -- will allow you to remove sites from the [Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334)

What you will need to do is:

1. Visit https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools
2. Click **ADD A SITE**.
3. Follow the steps to Add and verify your site
4. Once verified under **Configuration** > **Sitelinks** you will have the option to remove the offending site.

Answer (score 1):

Your best recourse is probably to contact appspot and ask them to remove the offending account that made the clone. As far as Google, they might take it down under a DCMA request if it were infringing your copyrighted content, but I'm not sure if a calendar would be considered copyrightable.

Your best bet would be to buy your own domain name and host it there. The other site might still show up as the next result, but so long as it's on its own domain it will never attach any other users sites as subpage related result